# Optimization of groupby in python3

Tags: python, lambda, vectorization

I'm currently using following code:

```
r = sorted(r, key=lambda x: np.sum(np.sign(x[0])))
r_sign = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(r, lambda x: np.sum(np.sign(x[0])))]
```

and this repeats dozen of times. This lambda calculates sum of signs in first subarray in array x.

After using cProfile I found out that it takes fifth of all program time to execute this lambdas.
Is there any way to make this faster?

EDIT:
Sample r:

```
[
[[0.00951770648888711 , -0.010632367736364043 ,-0.00762821730429671 ], [43.41121518753604 , 42.95209626953438 , 42.62569485872547 ]],
[[-0.006837011753845527 ,-0.0635460919772306 , -0.00000010000000494736474], [42.70701121975766 , 40.077577445066126 , 40.07757343730839 ]],
[[-0.00805079210543345 ,0.00013611978285009367 , -0.00928941925049471 ],[42.65520573526393 , 42.66101234779449 ,42.26655131202322 ]],
[[0.0053552539095161516 ,0.034029663355880035 ,0.0040874730381727006 ], [43.23089361326043 , 44.72734381081924 ,44.91053977192976 ]],
[[-0.00995255607863394 ,0.003448983498802789 , -0.008569474771224724 ], [42.574162688526165 , 42.721253784685985 ,42.35671924378283 ]],
[[0.007829733915254721 ,-0.029076385744620153 , 0.01793276260136461 ], [43.33800005686172 ,42.096031132792795 , 42.85773861262677 ]],
[[0.030049593754386345 ,0.02425545805866335 , 0.0007543244036476204 ], [44.3117424911824 ,45.399685036745204 ,45.43394404666549 ]],
[[-0.031584760068658485 ,-0.024818728517988022 , -0.00604796913646777 ], [41.66307961235872 ,40.64178103974877 , 40.3967226022796 ]],
[[-0.024428341523493616 ,0.012410082068531779 , -0.010577084021758344 ],[41.96230747078123 , 42.48630786915531 ,42.03929483570234 ]],
[[-0.023662332321561542 ,0.004586640946688178 , 0.001141053576375452 ], [41.99446329869585 ,42.18751922425499 , 42.2356849185371 ]],
]
```

Comment: Could you post a small sample of your `r`?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso Thanks for you reply. Edited.

Comment: That's 10 different lists, not one. Is there a third dimension, or do you mean to concatenate them,...?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso If I got you right yes there's a third dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the calculation of the `lambda` is where your bottleneck is, compute it once and only once.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np

r = np.array(
    [[[ 9.5e-03, -1.1e-02, -7.6e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.3e+01]],
     [[-6.8e-03, -6.4e-02, -1.0e-07], [4.3e+01, 4.0e+01, 4.0e+01]],
     [[-8.1e-03,  1.4e-04, -9.3e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[ 5.4e-03,  3.4e-02,  4.1e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.5e+01, 4.5e+01]],
     [[-1.0e-02,  3.4e-03, -8.6e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[ 7.8e-03, -2.9e-02,  1.8e-02], [4.3e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.3e+01]],
     [[ 3.0e-02,  2.4e-02,  7.5e-04], [4.4e+01, 4.5e+01, 4.5e+01]],
     [[-3.2e-02, -2.5e-02, -6.0e-03], [4.2e+01, 4.1e+01, 4.0e+01]],
     [[-2.4e-02,  1.2e-02, -1.1e-02], [4.2e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[-2.4e-02,  4.6e-03,  1.1e-03], [4.2e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.2e+01]]])
```

(I have truncated a bit your numbers). Start by computing the `lambda` and keeping with it *only* the index of your list-of-two-lists-with-three-elements — no need to carry along all of the data.

```
indices = [(np.sum(np.sign(x[0])), i) for i, x in enumerate(r)]
print(indices)

# [(-1.0, 0), (-3.0, 1), (-1.0, 2), (3.0, 3), (-1.0, 4),
#  (1.0, 5), (3.0, 6), (-3.0, 7), (-1.0, 8), (1.0, 9)]
```

Sort the above list of tuples by the values in their first entry.

```
indices = sorted(indices, key=itemgetter(0))
print(indices)

# [(-3.0, 1), (-3.0, 7), (-1.0, 0), (-1.0, 2), (-1.0, 4),
#  (-1.0, 8), (1.0, 5), (1.0, 9), (3.0, 3), (3.0, 6)]
```

You can now do your `groupby` to collect together the indices of the rows with the same key.

```
extract_indices = lambda g: [x[1] for x in list(g)]
grouped_indices = [(k, extract_indices(g))
                   for k, g in groupby(indices, key=itemgetter(0))]
print(grouped_indices)

# [(-3.0, [1, 7]), (-1.0, [0, 2, 4, 8]), (1.0, [5, 9]), (3.0, [3, 6])]
```

Take advantage of numpy's fancy indexing to extract the rows with the indices above from the original data (if you're not interested in the key, you can throw it away).

```
groups = [(k, r[i]) for k, i in grouped_indices]
print(groups)

# [(-3.0, array([[[ -6.8e-03, -6.4e-02, -1.0e-07],
#                 [  4.3e+01,  4.0e+01,  4.0e+01]],
#                [[ -3.2e-02, -2.5e-02, -6.0e-03],
#                 [  4.2e+01,  4.1e+01,  4.0e+01]]])),
#  (-1.0, array([[[  9.5e-03, -1.1e-02, -7.6e-03],
#                 [  4.3e+01,  4.3e+01,  4.3e+01]],
#                [[ -8.1e-03,  1.4e-04, -9.3e-03],
#                 [  4.3e+01,  4.3e+01,  4.2e+01]],
#                [[ -1.0e-02,  3.4e-03, -8.6e-03],
#                 [  4.3e+01,  4.3e+01,  4.2e+01]],
#                [[ -2.4e-02,  1.2e-02, -1.1e-02],
#                 [  4.2e+01,  4.2e+01,  4.2e+01]]])),
#  ( 1.0, array([[[  7.8e-03, -2.9e-02,  1.8e-02],
#                 [  4.3e+01,  4.2e+01,  4.3e+01]],
#                [[ -2.4e-02,  4.6e-03,  1.1e-03],
#                 [  4.2e+01,  4.2e+01,  4.2e+01]]])),
#  ( 3.0, array([[[  5.4e-03,  3.4e-02,  4.1e-03],
#                 [  4.3e+01,  4.5e+01,  4.5e+01]],
#                [[  3.0e-02,  2.4e-02,  7.5e-04],
#                 [  4.4e+01,  4.5e+01,  4.5e+01]]]))]
```

This runs 20% faster than your code. Here's some benchmarking.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np

r = np.array(
    [[[ 9.5e-03, -1.1e-02, -7.6e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.3e+01]],
     [[-6.8e-03, -6.4e-02, -1.0e-07], [4.3e+01, 4.0e+01, 4.0e+01]],
     [[-8.1e-03,  1.4e-04, -9.3e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[ 5.4e-03,  3.4e-02,  4.1e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.5e+01, 4.5e+01]],
     [[-1.0e-02,  3.4e-03, -8.6e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[ 7.8e-03, -2.9e-02,  1.8e-02], [4.3e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.3e+01]],
     [[ 3.0e-02,  2.4e-02,  7.5e-04], [4.4e+01, 4.5e+01, 4.5e+01]],
     [[-3.2e-02, -2.5e-02, -6.0e-03], [4.2e+01, 4.1e+01, 4.0e+01]],
     [[-2.4e-02,  1.2e-02, -1.1e-02], [4.2e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[-2.4e-02,  4.6e-03,  1.1e-03], [4.2e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.2e+01]]])

def approach1():
    r1 = sorted(r, key=lambda x: np.sum(np.sign(x[0])))
    r_sign1 = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(r, lambda x: np.sum(np.sign(x[0])))]

def approach2():
    indices = [(np.sum(np.sign(x[0])), i) for i, x in enumerate(r)]
    indices = sorted(indices, key=itemgetter(0))

    extract_indices = lambda g: [x[1] for x in list(g)]
    grouped_indices = [(k, extract_indices(g))
                       for k, g in groupby(indices, key=itemgetter(0))]

    groups = [(k, r[i]) for k, i in grouped_indices]

%timeit approach1()     # => 10000 loops, best of 3: 105 µs per loop
%timeit approach2()     # => 10000 loops, best of 3: 82 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. This isn't something I expected but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is way slower than my other answer or your code — it takes almost 4ms on my machine —, but it is more concise and easier to reason about, so I'm leaving it here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r = [[[ 9.5e-03, -1.1e-02, -7.6e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.3e+01]],
     [[-6.8e-03, -6.4e-02, -1.0e-07], [4.3e+01, 4.0e+01, 4.0e+01]],
     [[-8.1e-03,  1.4e-04, -9.3e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[ 5.4e-03,  3.4e-02,  4.1e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.5e+01, 4.5e+01]],
     [[-1.0e-02,  3.4e-03, -8.6e-03], [4.3e+01, 4.3e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[ 7.8e-03, -2.9e-02,  1.8e-02], [4.3e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.3e+01]],
     [[ 3.0e-02,  2.4e-02,  7.5e-04], [4.4e+01, 4.5e+01, 4.5e+01]],
     [[-3.2e-02, -2.5e-02, -6.0e-03], [4.2e+01, 4.1e+01, 4.0e+01]],
     [[-2.4e-02,  1.2e-02, -1.1e-02], [4.2e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.2e+01]],
     [[-2.4e-02,  4.6e-03,  1.1e-03], [4.2e+01, 4.2e+01, 4.2e+01]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key', 'elements'])
df['elements'] = r
df['key'] = df['elements'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.sign(x[0])))
s = df.groupby('key')['elements'].apply(list)
groups = [(k, g) for k, g in s.iteritems()]
```